# Invoking Script on Mendix

Tags: terraform, mendix

I have a fully functioning terraform script which provisions infrastructure on the vSphere. I am trying to run/invoke it through the Mendix platform. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Terraform expert but a Mendix expert. AFAIK I understand is Terraform an application that controls infrastructure.

There are some possibilities:

1. Invoke terraform via a SDK or API to start the scripts.
2. Use the Terraform java client and rewrite the scripts in a Mendix Java-Action.
3. Use a javascript-action to call the API from typescript
4. Write a custom widget to call the API from typescript.